# UI-Router nested views won't render (No errors)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my Angular UI project I have nested views in my config. When I load the web page in my browser, these nested views do not display, although the controller fires and the parent view renders correctly. Everything that is supposed to be on scope is on scope as well.

Here's my config

```
angular.module('quizApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  templateUrl: 'components/home/homeView.html',
  controller: 'homeCtrl',
  url: '/'
})
.state('quiz', {
  controller: 'quizCtrl',
  url: '/quiz/:quizName',
  templateUrl: 'components/quiz/views/quizContainerView.html'
})
.state('quiz.view', {
  parent: 'quiz',
  views: {
    'list': {
      templateUrl: 'components/quiz/views/questionListWrapperView.html'
    },
    'detail': {
      templateUrl: 'components/quiz/views/questionDetailView.html'
    }
  }
})
})
```

quiz.view list and detail are expected to show up on the page.

Here's my repo
https://github.com/asBrettisay/psychic-octo-eureka

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you ever figure it out? asking for a *friend*

Answer (score 0):

You missed the url atrribute on the child view

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  templateUrl: 'components/home/homeView.html',
  controller: 'homeCtrl',
  url: '/'
})
.state('quiz', {
  controller: 'quizCtrl',
  url: '/quiz/:quizName',
  templateUrl: 'components/quiz/views/quizContainerView.html'
})
.state('quiz.view', {
  parent: 'quiz',
  url: '/something',
  views: {
    'list': {
      templateUrl: 'components/quiz/views/questionListWrapperView.html'
    },
    'detail': {
      templateUrl: 'components/quiz/views/questionDetailView.html'
    }
  }
})
})
```

the nested view will be /quiz/:quizName/something